# Npm install git https address but it looks for SSH instead

Tags: node.js, git, ssh, https, node-modules

Hi I am looking for some help on installing private in-house npm modules in a Node project.

I just started writing a node library which I can install by specifying its git's url.

The problem I have is: I specified the dependency let say `sample_module`:

`git+https://{token}:x-oauth-basic@github.com:{repo_org/repo_name}`

However when I do `npm install`, it installs via ssh.

I want to use https only because of certain rules in collaboration. May I know if I could know why even if I specify https in the module url, it still goes to ssh protocol? How should I force or change it to HTTPS only?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think your **sample_module** is set up to also support ssh, note the `git` in `git+https://`

Try setting the remote url as `https://{token}:x-oauth-basic@github.com:{repo_org/repo_name}` to see if it helps to default the behavior to use just https.

See https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/